# how to discover two or more slaves using bacnet demo servers and bacnet demo client?

Tags: master-slave, sourceforge, rs485, bacnet

I am using Bacnet stack(0.8.3) in order to develop a Bacnet MSTP client. Initially, I run the demo server and read property client through MSTP. It's working.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/bacnet/

Now, I am trying to run two different servers with different object instance and different mac address to establish a communication with Bacnet client one after the other by giving the object instance at console end of Bacnet client(readprop). I am able to establish communication between client and server-1 but not with server-2.

Please help me , how to discover more slaves using Bacnet demo readproperty client?

Regards,
P. Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the correct Device Instance when executing readprop? (give us a clue.... what are you entering as command line parameters for readprop? What are the Device Instances of your two test servers?)